# Include multiple JavaScript files in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, yui

does CoffeeScript have someting that can say: include this, that file.
so the JS files are spread and modular but a "compiling" brings them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. CoffeeScript files map 1-to-1 with their .js counterpart. The bundling you describe is possible with other projects such as [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) and [browserify](http://browserify.org/), among several others.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at something like [brunch.io](http://brunch.io) to combine all your .coffee files into a single app.js file.